# JSON to Export .txt Order in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, output

I have this code, and the string is coming from JSON from the server, and I use these if statements to prioritize what I want to get exported to the text file, but when I run it, the output isnt the output I am expecting, see below:

```
JSONObject attributeObject = objects.getJSONObject(objectAttribute);
String[] elementList = JSONObject.getNames(attributeObject);

for (String attributeName : elementList) {
if (attribute.equals("Custodian")){
    String value = objects.getString("attributeValue");
    System.out.print(value+",");
    out.write(value);
    out.append(",");
}
if (attribute.equals("Custodian Delegate")){
    String value = objects.getString("attributeValue");
    System.out.print(value+",");
    out.write(value);
    out.append(",");
}

if (attribute.equals("Authentication Directory")){
    String value = objects.getString("attributeValue");
    System.out.print(value+",");
    out.write(value);
    out.append(",");
}
if (attribute.equals("User ID")){
    String value = objects.getString("attributeValue");
    System.out.println(value);
    out.write(value);
    out.append(",");
    out.newLine();
    }  
}
```

Expected output based from the if statements:
**JDoe,CPer,Active Directory, No**

But once I run it, the output becomes:
**Active Directory,JDoe,CPer,No**

Is there an easier way to fix this? My only problem is that the Authentication Directory goes first when I start running the program. Any tips? I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try using `switch case`

Comment: @Mohit how is that gonna help?

Comment: if your code part of a loop?

Comment: @Mohit the possible cause is Active Directory was created first, and when Im parsing the json file, it gets what was created first

Comment: @nafas yes, it's in a for loop

Comment: First there is `String` object created on every if statement which is not good practice, and in `switch case` it wont go for full loop of checking process as `if()` it will `break;` as it find desire value.. but where also I would recommend to create only single object because `String` itself is **immutable**

Comment: I does not matter if your code is part of `for()` loop, just create a method with `switch case` which return desire string..

Comment: Is he given output from the file or console?

Comment: @Mohit how will I implement a switch case if I have (attribute.equals("Custodian"), (attribute.equals("Custodian Delegate"))...

Comment: @masinger it's from a .txt

Comment: just use your text `".."` inside you `.equals()` as value for switch statement

Comment: Can you please add the surrounding loop?

Comment: @masinger I added the surrounding loop already

Answer (score 0):

make your life easy by creating a `Model` class

```
class Model{

  String JDoe="";  //this is an example, so change attribute names using naming convention
  String CPer="";
  String Active_Directory=""; 
  String No="";

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return JDoe+", " +CPer+", " +Active_Directory+", " + No;
  }
}
```

now change your code to use this model, and only update the class Model without writing anything to the file.

for example:

```
Model model = new Model();
...
for(whatever condition is){ //start of the loop
  if (attribute.equals("Custodian")){
    String value = objects.getString("attributeValue");
    model.CPer=value;
    //System.out.print(value+",");
    //out.write(value); <-- skip this
    //out.append(",");  <-- skip this
  }
  ...
}
//after the loop 
 out.write(model.toString());
```

NOTE:

if you have two loops place  `Model model = new Model();` 
inside your outter loop

Comment: how will I be able to name and get each of them if I'm getting it from this line of code:  

**String attribute = attributeObject.getString("attributeName");** This line of code gets  Custodian, Custodian Delegate, Active Directory.and User ID

Comment: @JohnDoe I've edited the answer, its not really hard mate, just try to understand it

Answer (score 0):

The output might be correct. You are iterating over all keys of the JSON-object. The resulting order does not depend on the order of your if-satements. In every loop only a single if-condition matches. The given snippet will output the elements in the same order as in the returned array.

The .getNames() returnes the array of the field names of the given Object. Then you are iterating over theses field names. Therfore the attribute value will have the same value per cycle. It is impossible that two if-condition will match because attribute can not equal for example "Custodian" and "Custodian Delegate" at thes same time.

It seems like the array contains the attributes in an alphabetic order. Therefore the attributeName-variable is "Authentication Directory" during the first cycle.

Comment: what do you mean given snippet will output the elements in the same order as in the returned array?